# AFHttpclient get json body in block but outer function returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I am trying to send post request on some url and in body to be only json data (trying to register new user sending json like

```
{
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "email": "email@gmail.com"
}
```

I have function like

```
-(NSString*) sendPostOnUrl:(NSString*) url
            withParameters:(NSDictionary*)params{
    __block NSString* response = nil;
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *u = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL: u];

    [httpClient postPath:REGISTER
              parameters:params
                 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                     response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                     NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", response);
                 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                     NSLog(@"[HTTPClient Error]: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                 }];
    return response;
}
```

where params are NSDictionary with keys username, password and email and values for those keys.
Problem is when I send I always in return get null in response (the latest line) but in NSLog I get json response.. I am very new to ios, and it looks to me that I need to sync on some way block with return from function but don't know how, can anybody give me a clue what am I doing wrong ? (params contains all those keys when I try to debug, url is ok, REGISTER is NSString constant)

Answer (score 1):

Blocks are asynchronous  - the problem here is that "response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData..." is within the block which gets executed after you've exited the method. A better approach is to not do this in a method, instead place this code where you were calling sendPostOnUrl:withParameters: and do whatever it is you need to do within the success block. So instead of:

```
self.something = [self sendPostOnUrl:url withParameters:@{"username":"test" etc}];
```

you do this:

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *u = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL: u];
__weak YourClassName *me = self;
[httpClient postPath:REGISTER
          parameters:params
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                 me.something = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                 NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", response);
             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"[HTTPClient Error]: %@", error.localizedDescription);
             }];
```

Also, take note of "__weak YourClassName *me = self", you cannot reference self within a block because it will cause a retain cycle.

Comment: Do you really need the weak self here? Where does the object creating this block retain it?

Comment: @CarlVeazey Under ARC blocks automatically retain any objects they capture. I assumed this was ARC code.